# Applications of Voronoi without Delaunay?

Tags: graph, voronoi, delaunay

So if this is true:
[How to query a Voronoi diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213517/how-to-query-a-voronoi-diagram)

> The question "Which site does a given point belong to?" is just another way of stating the nearest neighbor search problem: the relevant Voronoi polygon is the one associated with the nearest point in the set generating the Voronoi diagram. Unfortunately,
>
> - there isn't any constant time algorithm for solving this problem, and
> - the Voronoi diagram doesn't provide any solving the problem faster than an O(N) search.

How *do* we actually use them?

I mean, I am aware of the Delaunay-based search tree that I can construct for it, but I don't *need* a Voronoi diagram to construct a Delaunay Triangulation now, do I?

So what practical purposes - except, say, printing it on a map for easier human digestion - does Voronoi serve?

What problems *can* be solved with just a Voronoi Diagram without its dual (in a more efficient manner than without it, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the access pattern. Since the two graphs are dual, both contain basically the same information. From practical experience, however, computing the Voronoi vertices requires expensive multiple-precision arithmetic on a case-by-case basis, since there are degenerate settings and since there are infinite and nearly-infinite Voronoi cells. Therefore, depending on the access pattern, it will often be more efficient to compute the Voronoi diagram *once* instead of using the Delaunay triangulation and computing its dual elements over and over again.

On the other hand, nearest neighbor search in a Delaunay triangulation is much simpler, thus I have chosen a hybrid data representation for my [Voronoi diagram](https://www.geom.at/example12-voronoi-diagram/). It uses the Delaunay triangulation *and* a Voronoi representation on top of it and so points can be located in O(log(n)) time. The performance indicates that this is a good approach: for one million queries in a Voronoi diagram with n=1000 sites, only 0.3 seconds are needed.

EDIT: For nearest neighbor queries you don't need Voronoi cells. But for algorithms which are interested in the boundary or in the area of a Voronoi cell. Just a few examples: [Centroidal Voronoi Tesselation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroidal_Voronoi_tessellation), [Natural Neighbor Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_neighbor_interpolation), [Medial Axis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2845976_Approximating_the_Medial_Axis_from_the_Voronoi_Diagram_with_a_Convergence_Guarantee)

Comment: Hm ... this doesn't really adress my question. Why do I want to retrieve the voronoi cell anyway? I mean in my mind, the great thing about Voronoi is that if I know the cell my query point is in, I know exactly what site is closest to my query point.

But if all I'm interested in is the nearest site and I can find that via the delaunay triangulation easily enough ... why do I need Voronoi at all?

Comment: If you are only interested in nearest neighbor queries you don't need Voronoi cells. But you asked why one could need a Voronoi diagram at all. This is the case for algorithms which are interested in the boundary or in the area of a Voronoi cell. Find just two examples here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroidal_Voronoi_tessellation and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_neighbor_interpolation

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. :) 
Could you incorporate your comment about when you actually use Voronoi diagrams into your answer?